# Best way to write method with same business logic for different parameters and type?

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to write a method with the same business logic for different parameters and type?

Example:

I have the following method:

```
void condition(int a)
{ 
    if (a in range of)
    {
        log something with a;
    } else {
        log something with a;
    }
}
```

Here I need the same method to be called for different data types and I also need to log with the specific name of the field we pass to this method, for example:

```
condition(b);
```

should log b in the statement.

Comment: What does 'a in range of' do i.e. what types will the method accept?

Comment: post a runnable example, dont ask question with no specific answer. Is there a way to improve your method? yes.. paste a runnable code if you want specific answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ? (rplace sout by a great logger)

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Condition<T> {

    public void test(Predicate<T> predicate, T aValue, String logIf, String logElse) {
        System.out.println(predicate.test(aValue) ? logIf : logElse);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Condition<Integer> conditionInteger = new Condition<>();
        conditionInteger.test( v ->  v < 10, 15, "Log If with an integer", "log else with an integer");

        Condition<String> conditionString = new Condition<>();
        conditionString.test( v -> v.length() < 10, "a great String", "Log If with a string", "log else with a string");
    }
}
```